# jQuery get and parsing html unexpected behaviour with parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$.get( load_this, function( page ) {

            $article = $( page ).find( ".js-Article--current" );

            console.log( $(page) );

            $article.removeClass( "js-Article--current" ).addClass( "Article--contentHidden" )
                    .children( ".js-ArticleHeader" )     .addClass( "ArticleHeader--teaser" )
                    .find( ".next-teaserFade" )          .addClass( "ArticleHeader-teaserFade" )
                    .end()
                    .find( ".next-teaserSqueeze" )       .addClass( "ArticleHeader-teaserSqueeze" );

            $( ".js-Article--current" ).after( $article );

        });
```

get returns whole page.

Now problem I've encountered is this:

if `js-Article--current` is not top level element find finds it.

if `js-Article--current` is top level element find cannot find it.

Why?

p.s. I know solution: **filter** instead of **find**. But why is find behaving like this? I don't get it.

Comment: find() will try to find a child element of the selectro. So, if .js-Article--current is the selector, it will not find it. fIlter(), instead, filters through the selectors

Comment: _returns whole page._ is this with doctype and body etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find()` will try to find a child element of the selector. So, if `.js-Article--current` is the selector, it will not find it.

`filter()`, instead, filters through the selectors

Check the console:

```js
var findTest = $('div').find('#test').length;
var filterTest = $('div').filter('#test').length;

console.log('find test: ' + findTest);
console.log('filter test: ' + filterTest);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="anotherTest"></div>
```